# Codeigniter doesn't insert record to database but there is no error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to create an address book online but whenever I try to add a new contact, it doesn't insert the record to the database.

Here is my code.

Controller

```
public function addcontact(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('contacts');

    $first_name = $_GET['inputFirstName'];
    $last_name = $_GET['inputLastName'];
    $contact_number = $_GET['inputContactNumber'];
    $address = $_GET['inputAddress'];
    $email_address = $_GET['inputEmailAddress'];
    $image;
    if(isset($_POST['inputPicture'])){
        if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE){
            //please select image
        }
        else{
            $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image = file_get_contents($image);
            $image = base64_encode($image);
        }
    }

    $data['first_name'] = $this->filter_input($first_name);
    $data['last_name'] = $this->filter_input($last_name);
    $data['contact_number'] = $this->filter_input($contact_number);
    $data['address'] = $this->filter_input($address);
    $data['email_address'] = $this->filter_input($email_address);
    $data['picture'] = $image;

    $this->contacts->addContacts($first_name, $last_name, $contact_number, $address, $email_address, $image);


    $data['title'] = 'Address Book';
    $data['contacts_info'] = $this->contacts->getContacts();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);

}
```

Model

```
function addContacts($first_name, $last_name, $contact_number, $address, $email_address, $image){

    $new_contact_data = array(
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'contact_number' => $contact_number,
        'address' => $address,
        'email_address' => $email_address,
        'picture' => $image,
    );

    $this->db->insert('contacts', $new_contact_data);
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

I know that I can connect to my database because I can load all the record in my homepage just fine. I'm just having trouble adding records to the database.

Comment: in your model , before you insert the array, check whats inside the array , var_dump($new_contact_data); does it return the right values that you sent ?

Comment: Modify your `insert` statement to something like `if (!$this->db->insert('contacts',$new_contact_data)) { echo $this->db->_error_message(); } else { echo 'success'; }`. Let us know what you get.